# High res display: will it upscale from my low res laptop video?

Tags: hdmi, external-display, 4k-resolution

My 4 year old Vaio/windows 7 has an hdmi port, and I regularly use it with a Dell UltraSharp U2410 x 1920 x 1080. This is a "regular" dpi display (92 dpi or so)

I want to use it with a 4k or 5k display (such as an ASUS PB279Q 27" 4K/ UHD 3840x2160).

But I am worried that everything will be small.

Do high res displays smartly resample to get it right in this situation?

Or ?

Comment: You should first see if your graphics can even support a 4K resolution, especially if you have integrated graphics. Secondly, assuming your HDMI is v1.4 it can only support full 4K `4096×2160` at 24 Hz or `3840×2160 (Ultra HD)` at 24 Hz/25 Hz/30 Hz.

Comment: @drzoo no. Graphics card in laptop cannot support 4k. That is why I ask if monitor will upscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

The Vaio laptop in question has a built in display of 1920x1080, and the external hdmi supports a max res of 1920x1080.

When we plug the ASUS PB279Q (which is 3840 x 2160) in to the hdmi port, the monitor automatically upscales the output.

Some output is a tad blurred, but overall it looks very good.

(Yes, we actually purchased the ASUS PB279Q... and got lucky. This thread was attempt to reduce the luck factor...)